# PHP - Remove content of a tag if it's content starts with certain text

Tags: php, regex

I have a situation here, could you please help me to do this. I have string like -

```
Someother string \n\n or anything[img]data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAAN........[/img]aaa
```

Also some like this -

```
anything[img]http://imagepath.com/image.png[/img]aaa
```

I want to remove `[img]` tag if it starts with / contain `data:image` in `[img]` tag.

Regex will be great.

I tried this -

```
preg_replace('#data:image/[^;]+;base64,#', '', $string);
```

but not providing expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$string = preg_replace('/\[img\]data:image.*?\[\/img\]/', '', $string);
```

Simple test script:

```
<?php
$string = 'Stack [img]data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAAN...[/img] Overflow';

$string = preg_replace('/\[img\]data:image.*?\[\/img\]/s', '', $string);

echo "$string\n";
?>
```

Output is:

```
Stack  Overflow
```

Comment: Thank you it works! :) I have a database and there is tons of this. I need to fix database.sql file by this.

Comment: If your strings are very large, this regex will cause a crash. It does not support newline symbols between `[img]`and `[/img]`, either.

Comment: It's actually not that large only 5MB gzip sql file. I have done like this - http://codeshare.io/FI1kH and it complied in less than a second. So i guess more larger file will be okay. Do you have any better suggestion?

Comment: FYI - I've edited to allow for newlines between the opening and closing `[img]` tags.

Comment: /s does the trick for newline? possibly i don't have any line & it didn't crashed :)

Comment: Correct, the `s` modifier makes `.` match newlines. I don't know how bit it has to be to cause a crash, but I guess it's possible for large strings.